# Cannot SSH to headless RPI Zero W via USB

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, ssh, pi-zero-w

I am unable to access my RPI Zero W v1.1 with SSH through USB.

I'm using a fresh install of the RPI OS Lite 32 bit version through the official Imager (1.7.4), with a custom username/password, custom host, and SSH enabled (set to password authentication).

This all works perfectly when plugged into an RPI 3 with ethernet - everything connects and I can use SSH fine. However, I am unable to use SSH to connect to the pi via the USB connection on the RPI Zero. Am unable to see the device or ping it while it is plugged in and booted up.

Here are some of the I've tried so far:

- Installing the RNDIS drivers for Windows
- Installing Bonjour and iTunes
- Modifying both the `config.txt` and the `cmdline.txt` to contain `dtoverlay=dwc2` and `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` respectively
- Multiple USB cords
- Manually creating first boot files

With all of these, I cannot see the pi on the network or connect with it.

After installing the RNDIS drivers, I cannot see the device plugged in, and it does not show up under `Network Adapters` or `Ports (COM & LPT)`. I have this same issue on both Windows 10 and Windows 11.

The RPI Zero is booting up properly, as when attached to a monitor it is sitting on the login prompt.

Comment: Your question lacks detail. If the Pi Zero W is connected to your router there is no need to use any other connection and attempting to use multiple connections can be problematic. What does `ip a && ip r` show? How are you attempting to `access my RPI Zero W v1.1 with SSH through USB`?

Comment: The Pi Zero is not connect to my router, it's connected directly to my computer with USB. The pi does not show up on the network at all, and has no ip.

Previously I was able to use SSH to connect to the Pi Zero by simply having it plugged into the computer and the USB port on the Pi Zero (the more central one), but I am unable to do so now.

Comment: Interestingly, the problem seems to have fixed itself.

I am now able to see the piin Device Manager, and I can connect to it fine. Not sure what changed, but everything works fine now.